# Comparing two dataframes if one contains the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `A` and `B`. For example:

A:

```
Key | Col1 | Col2 
 A     aa     bb 
 B     bb     bc
 C     cc     bd
```

B:

```
Key | Col1 | Col2 
 A     a       b     
 B     ab      c  
 C     cc      b
```

Both have one unique row per key(which is a key of the df), and can hold different values for the other columns.

I'm trying to analyzing the difference between the two dataframes.

I want 3 comparisons(possibly 4).

1. number of `notna` cells in `A` per column
2. number of records that are equal, divided by the number of cells with a `notna` value in `A` per column
3. number of records in `B`, that is in `A` string wise(for instance 'aaa' is in 'baaab') per column
4. some other custom comparison. I.E. Some similarity measure.

I've managed to achieve `1` and `2`, using this:

```
counts = A.notna().sum()
scores = B.eq(A).sum().div(counts)
```

So for `3`, I want to get:

```
Col1    2
Col2    3
```

My problem is that I don't know how to achieve a custom comparison like `in` for my third and forth options.. If both were in the same df, then I could probably do something like this

```
df[col] = df.apply(lambda x: x[col + '_1'] in x[col + '+2'], axis=1)
```

For each column, and sum the result, but that seems complicated and messy. Any suggestion for a cleaner solution with both dataframes apart?

Comment: I think that you need to share a reproducible example of A and B. Also, you need to be more specific because in 4 you say _some other custom comparison_.

Comment: @Timeless I've added an example for my data and expected output. For 4 I mean as it sounds.. any comparison that I will think of, not necessarily in. Like some similarity measure

Answer (score 1):

For `3)`, you can go down to numpy an call [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy-vectorize) to apply python's *built-in* [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to all the elements of an array in one shot. The function will return `True` if the substring is found (not -1) and `False`, otherwise.

> `str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found
> within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are
> interpreted as in slice notation. **Return -1 if sub is not found**.

```
#is B values are substrings of A values ? 
ma = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x.find(y) != -1)(A, B)
​
res3 = pd.DataFrame(ma, columns=B.columns).set_index("Key").sum()
```

Output :

```
print(res3)

Col1    2
Col2    3
dtype: int64
```

And regarding `4)`, you may want to use [`fuzz.ratio`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/af443f918eebbccff840b86fa606ac150563f466/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py#L24) with a *listcomp* the calculate a similarity measure, i.e, the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two strings of each pair/column `(A/B)`.

```
#pip install fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

levenshtein_distance = [[fuzz.ratio(x, y)
                         for x, y in zip(A[col], B[col])]
                         for col in A.columns if col != "Key"]

print(levenshtein_distance)
#[[67, 50, 100], [67, 67, 67]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For #3, because the brunt of the work is spent on string searching, vectorization is unlikely to solve any critical bottlenecks. Something simple like this should get you what your question asks for:

```py
cols = [label for label in B.columns if label != 'Key']
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[B.loc[r,c] in A.loc[r,c] for c in cols] for r in B.index], columns = cols).sum()
```

Output:

```
Col1    2
Col2    3
```